# Insulating a vaulted/cathedral ceiling

Tags: renovation

I am located in Melbourne, Australia and my house built in the mid 1980’s with exposed beams/joists. The roof is made of cement tiles.

I am looking at adding insulation from the inside of the ceiling as this is exposed relatively easy to access, I then plan to either add more ceiling cladding or plaster over the exposed roof.

The existing joists/rafters are 900mm apart and I have been recommended to add additional fixing points between the existing joists to support the new cladding/plasterboard.

Can anyone recommend the best way to approach this? In terms of running additional joists between the existing ones.

I do also have beams running perpendicular to the joists. [image]

Comment: Ventilation will be your problem.

Comment: What is in between the ceiling and the roof? Is there already insulation in there?  What type? How thick? Which region? If you get snow, there should be a ventilated air space between the insulation and the roof, to allow the roof to be cold in the winter and avoid ice dams. With answers to these questions, it'll be possible to make recommendations.

Comment: In many cases the best way to approach this is by insulating the other side - adding insulation on the roof itself.

Comment: The "best" way is unclear (and largely a matter of opinion, motivation, and budget). Please research the common approaches (hot roof, exterior overlay, stacked trusses, etc.) and revise to ask something more specific and objective.

Comment: I owned a house w/a similar post and beam construction.  The insulation was outside between the tar roofing and the wooden post and beam construction.  The insulation had to be several inches as there was a noticeable drop in the height of the roof surface over non-living spaces (over hang and garage).  Is that a brick wall in the picture?  Any insulation between it and the outside?  Depending on where you live, I would say ceiling insulation is the least of your worries.

Comment: What *type* of insulation are you looking at adding?  Fluffy insulations such as fiberglass and celluose are very different beasts than a spray foam in this situation...

Comment: My original question was regarding adding additional joists. To answer some of the comments that have been added so far. 

As far as I am award there is nothing between the roof tiles and cladding and there is very little space to fit anything in there that would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I've seen applied was to simply apply foam insulation sheets over the inner surface of the beams, then use long screws to apply plasterboard over that (required for fire safety, you can't just leave the foam exposed). I can't vouch for whether it's the best solution, but it was cheap, easy (with a panel lift to raise the material and hold it while it's fastened in place), and the inspector approved it.

Might be a good idea to talk to your local inspector's office first, to see if they're ok with the idea (or have a better one) and find out whether they'll want you to pull a permit.

Comment: This results in a "hot roof", which has several inherent problems depending on climate. I'd hesitate to suggest it without knowing more. Relying on inspectors for appropriate solutions isn't a good strategy--they can only tell you what's _legal_.

Comment: This was in California, so... I agree that it'd probably be better to have airflow above that, perhaps ridge vent and some kind of soffets.

Comment: Yes this is what I am thinking of doing. Adding insulation batts and then plaster or timber cladding over the top. As the current joists are 900mm apart I have been advised that additional joists will be required and I was wanting advice on the best method to achieve a good fixing point to hang the plasterboard /dry wall

Comment: @isherwood agreed about the hot roof, but A) There _has_ to be some insulation between the inner, visible ceiling and the exterior roof (house built in the 1980s...) so if there's ventilation this wouldn't be blocking it, B) the exterior roofing is concrete tile and I don't _think_ that's a problem for concrete, is it?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> My original question was regarding adding additional joists.

Let's say that you want to add fiberglass insulation. Fiberglass insulation is sold as batts or rolls, and the width of the batts or rolls is the standard distance between studs in a wall, in the US that'd be to fit 16" or 24" spacing. But you can always install the insulation perpendicular to the joists, and hold it place with wires, short  pieces of wood, whatever, until you install the ceiling covering or cladding, and the insulation will rest on the cladding. In other words, you do not need to add extra joists just for insulation.

However, you might need to add extra support for the cladding. For example, the cladding material you are using might require structural support every 40 or 50cm, whatever the manufacturer requires. You could install additional joists (although I think those in the pictures are rafters, not joists), but this is unnecessary. You can achieve the same effect using furring strips installed perpendicular to the current rafters.  Furring strips are cheaper and faster to install. Just make sure to space them at no more than the maximum span recommended by the manufacturer of the cladding -- different materials have different maximum spans, and even within the same materials the thickness of the material will determine the maximum span. If you are thinking of wood cladding, you might be pleasantly surprised to find a particular material with a maximum span of 1m, which means you can just screw it directly to your current rafters.

Comment: Ok I have checked the recommended specs for a 19mm board with is thicker than the 12mm one I originally intended to use and the maximum distance is 600mm so it would still need additional support

Comment: The easiest is just to use furring strips. These are just long pieces of wood 2cm x 5cm, or whatever is available locally. They are installed perpendicular to the joists. If the joists are not in the same plane, add shims to the furring strips.

Comment: Ok and then you would run the cladding in-line with the joists. Thanks